# My personal levy size suddenly decreased by more than 50%… what could have happened?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I don't know what happened, but in three months, without apparently anything of note happening, my *personal* levy size more or less halved.

I would stress out I'm talking about **personal** levy, not vassals. Is there something that can affect it?

I gave out a single city to a vassal, but clearly it's not that: it was a ~400 soldiers city, and we're talking about a ~11000 to <3000 drop.

My demesne is too big, but it was so even before (actually now it's 10/6 vs. 11/6 of before). I didn't change wife, I didn't change councilors. Maybe a different heir got voted, but I can't see how that could be related either.

I converted one of my counts to my religion, but, again, what she did in her own county could hardly affect what happens in *my* demesne…

I'm absolutely clueless about this, I'll attach a couple of screenshot, let me know if you need more data.

[image: Ledger, before]

[image: Ledger, after]

Some more screenshots.

I've just noticed a very strange things: the portraits of the females changed! Including the deceased ones… is that normal?

[image: Character, before]

[image: Character, after]

[image: Armies, before]

[image: Armies, after]

Comment: Did your martial skill suddenly change due to dying/regency/events?

Comment: @Studoku nope, it has actually increased by 1…

Comment: How long had you been over your demesne limit?

Comment: @Studoku might have been slightly more than these 3 months.

Comment: Being over the limit applies penalties to levy size and income that are applied over time. Try giving away the excess titles.

Comment: @Studoku ok I had no idea it worked like that, I would have expected a popup of some sorts when I moved the mouse pointer over the "limit exceeded" number in the top-right corner… I'll try tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Did you patch up recently?

Comment: @Affine yes, but **all** this happened after the patch. Before the patch I was playing the previous ruler, who died long after I installed it.

Comment: @Studoku I tried to give away all excess titles, and within days the limit increased back to 7.5k. Will you post that as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was 7.5k instead of 11k, though. I expected a bit less, sure, but this was a lot. I'll investigate.

Comment: You're no longer getting personal levies from the holdings you gave away. It's in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Controlling more holdings than your demesne limit allows gives you significant opinion, income, and levy penalties. These penalties do not affect you for a few months- giving you a chance to give away conquered lands before suffering penalties.

You were over your limit (significantly over your limit at that) for a few months and the levy penalties kicked in. To solve this, give away titles (or increase your demesne limit) so you are no longer above your demesne limit.

You won't get personal levies from the holdings you give away but you'll get more in total (and get vassal levies from the ones you give away).

Comment: One interesting exploit I've come across is that levies are not affected if they've already been raised. This may be game version dependent, and I haven't tested it in a while, but I've been able to raise levies of a county before giving it away or transferring vassal control to another vassal, effectively getting some troops out of thin air. This does not remove the maintenance cost, however, so it's only really applicable if you're ready to send them to war.